# Syntax Digram DITA - EDITED

Tags: xslt, ant, dita, dita-ot

I am really struggling to make syntax diagrams work. Our company got the sources dita files from IBM. Many docs have a lot of syntax diagrams inside, and tried with the latest DITA-OT kit and it doesnt work. Can someone help me on how to get the syntax diagrams work?

I downloaded the plugins from https://github.com/robander/svg-syntaxdiagrams and put it in the plugins folder. Added the plugins to the plugin.xml file, and edited the integrator file as well, but I am not getting the output. I have done something wrong, and not able to sort it out.

Grateful if somebody help me out in this case.

EDIT: As per suggestion, i tried and it didnt work. I tried with a fresh DITA download without my company plugin, and it worked fine. So think I have a problem with my plugins and associated files. Will look more.

Comment: Adding here a link to the detailed set of steps to install the plugin you received on the Oxygen forum: https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/post65650.html#p65650

Comment: @RaduCoravu Thank you. Appreciate it. It looks so simple yet not able to solve. Let me put it here on what I have done so far.

1. Extracted the folders and the files to /plugins location.
2. Edited the config/plugins.xml file and included whatever available here (https://github.com/robander/svg-syntaxdiagrams/blob/master/com.ibm.ditatools.svg-diagrams/plugin.xml)
3. If i type dita --plugins, i could see com.ibm.ditatools.svg-diagrams but dont see any change in output.

Comment: 4. if i tried to install using dita --install, i get ""Error: Target "integrate" does not exist in the project "com.xxx.pdf-print". where com.xxx.pdf-print is my company's pdf plugin.
5. I tried installing using the oxygen's integrate feature,it is success but dont see output.

Comment: On the page (https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/post65650.html#p65650), Alex gave a step by step instructions, i did the same and dont see the diagrams yet.

Comment: @RaduCoravu Thanks. I have edited. It is just not working alongwith my company plugin. Need to work on that.

Comment: Step 2, that manual editing of the plugins.xml should not have been done. Step 4 takes care of integrating all plugins and must end succesfully to install the syntax diag plugin, probably your company’s specific pdf plugin has some kind of problem which needs to be corrected.

Comment: If you are using Oxygen XML Editor and you can share your custom PDF plugin with us I could try to find some time to see why your PDF plugin breaks the DITA OT plugins installation. https://www.oxygenxml.com/techSupport.html

Comment: @RaduCoravu Thank you so much for offering your help. I will upload the file at https://www.oxygenxml.com/techSupport.html and let you know. I tried the following.
1. Downloaded the fresh DITA-OT, and installed the syntax diagrams plugins - Working fine. No problem.
2. From step 1, added my company plugin and ran dita -install. Plugin added, and I added the missing file. No error but the syntax diagrams are missing in the PDF output.
3. DITA OT3.6.1+my company plugin, added syntax diagrams and tried dita -install, getting an error.

Comment: Error: Target "dita2pdf2" does not exist in the project "com.21csw.pdf-print". It is used from target "dita2pdf". com.21csw.pdf-print is out PDF plugin. I will upload all in the link. Thanks again.

Comment: @RaduCoravu I have sent the files. Please look into it. Thanks.